# How to write a C program that reads a user input strings and prints only those are not ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’

Tags: c

I am trying to create a program that reads a user input strings and prints only those are not ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’. The following program can print string of characters. But how do I write a C program that reads a user input strings and prints only those are not ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’? I appreciate any help that I can get.

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
char name[30];
printf("Enter name: ");
gets(name);     // read string
printf("Name: ");
puts(name);    // display string
return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you mean by opposite?

Comment: https://www.programiz.com/c-programming/examples/remove-characters-string

Comment: I meant how I can write a C program that reads a user input strings and prints only those are not ‘a-z’ or ‘A-Z’. Sorry if my question made you confused @bunglehead

Comment: Please read [Why is the gets function so dangerous that it should not be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1694036/why-is-the-gets-function-so-dangerous-that-it-should-not-be-used)

Comment: @MehediHassan basically you read a string, do any filtering you need, and print it back.

Answer (score 1):

To start with... **Never** use `gets` (nor `scanf("%s" …`). Use `fgets`.

Then you just to iterate over the string and check if the individual character is in the range of characters you don't want to print.

```
#define MAX_LEN 30

int main()
{    
    char name[30];
    printf("Enter name: ");
    if (fgets(name, MAX_LEN, stdin) != NULL)
    {
         int i = 0;
         while (name[i])
         {
            if ((name[i] < 'a' || name[i] > 'z') &&
                (name[i] < 'A' || name[i] > 'Z'))
                putchar(name[i]);
            ++i;
         }
    }

    return 0;    
}
```

Input:

12john34BEN56 78Al9

Output:

```
Enter name: 12john34BEN56 78Al9

123456 789
```